# Group by multiple dates using one date column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose we have a grocery's daily price table in SSMS:

| item | date | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tomato | 1/1/2023 | 10 |
| tomato | 1/2/2023 | 11 |
| tomato | 1/3/2023 | 12 |
| tomato | 1/4/2023 | 9 |
| tomato | 1/5/2023 | 12 |
| tomato | 1/6/2023 | 11.5 |
| tomato | 1/7/2023 | 11.4 |
| kale | 1/1/2023 | 13 |
| kale | 1/2/2023 | 11 |
| kale | 1/3/2023 | 12 |
| kale | 1/4/2023 | 10 |
| kale | 1/5/2023 | 12 |
| kale | 1/6/2023 | 11.5 |
| kale | 1/7/2023 | 11.4 |

...

I'd like to calculate a running 3-day average price and the output would be like this:

| vegetable | three dates | average price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tomato | 1/1-1/3 | 11 |
| tomato | 1/2-1/4 | 10.67 |
| kale | 1/1-1/3 | 12 |
| kale | 1/2-1/4 | 11 |

...

### How can I do that? Thank you!

What if you cannot sort by date in the query? Let's say there's another column "city" in the table, and each city has its own price for each vegetable every day. We still want a three-day avg price chart for each vegetable (regardless of city).

Comment: What options have you considered? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: You might want to look into the `LAG()` and `LEAD()` functions or a windowed `AVG(...) OVER(...ROWS...)`. A lot depends on data consistency. Will there be any gaps or duplicate dates? How would you want to handle start (new product) and end (today or product withdrawn) cases?

Comment: Other alternatives involve joins - `...FROM Calendar C JOIN Data D ON D.date BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -1, C.date) AND DATEADD(day, 1, C.date) ...` OR `...FROM Data D JOIN Data DPrior ON DPrior.date = DATEADD(day, -1, D.date) JOIN Data DNext ON DNext.date = DATEADD(day, 1, D.date) ...`.

Comment: yes. There is going to be dup dates! I added one more column so the ask is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL [window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/#:%7E:text=A%20window%20function%20performs%20a,done%20with%20an%20aggregate%20function.) to get what you want.
See the following code as example:

```
WITH grocery_price_running_average AS (
SELECT
   item,
   dt,
   price,
   COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY dt ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) as num_row_prev_next,
   AVG(price) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY dt ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) as average_price,
   LAG(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY dt) as min_dt,
   LEAD(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY dt) as max_dt
FROM
  grocery_price
)
SELECT
   item,
   CONCAT(min_dt, ' to ' , max_dt) as three_dates,
   average_price
FROM
   grocery_price_running_average
WHERE
  num_row_prev_next=3
order by 
  1 DESC,2
```

[SQLFIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4ed84e/5)
[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I missed one column in my original question so I reedited it. the dates will have dup values.

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text - much easier for everyone to read.

Comment: Hi @883km, I have updated the query to handle the additional item column in the partition.

Comment: What if you cannot sort by date in the query? Let's say there's another column "city" in the table, and each city has its own price for each vegetable every day. We still want a three-day avg price chart for each vegetable (regardless of city).

Comment: Hi @883km, could you clarify whether you want the three-day avg price on per vegetable level or per (vegetable, city) level in this case?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when date(s) aren't present? We can work around that using a calendar table, or a rCTE to make the ranges:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Date DATE, Price DECIMAL(10,2))
INSERT INTO @Table (Date, Price) VALUES

('1/1/2023', 10  ),
('1/2/2023', 11  ),
('1/3/2023', 12  ),
('1/4/2023', 9   ),
('1/5/2023', 12  ),
('1/6/2023', 11.5),
('1/7/2023', 11.4)

;WITH startDate AS (
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-2,MIN(Date)) AS date FROM @Table
), endDate AS (
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,MAX(Date)) AS date FROM @Table
), allDates AS (
SELECT s.Date
  FROM startDate s
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,a.Date)
  FROM allDates a
    CROSS APPLY endDate e
 WHERE a.date <= e.Date
```

Now we can use this to join to the data, and start figuring out some averages:

```
SELECT MIN(t2.Date) AS StartDate, a.Date, AVG(t2.Price) AS AvgPrice, COUNT(t2.Date) AS DatesPresent
  FROM allDates a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table t1
      ON a.date = t1.Date
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table t2
      ON t1.Date BETWEEN t2.Date AND DATEADD(DAY,2,t2.Date)
 GROUP BY a.Date
 ORDER BY a.date
```

Starting with our pseudo calendar, we join twice to the table to fetch the relevant rows in the table for the range we want, and then group em up.

| StartDate | Date | AvgPrice | DatesPresent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | 2022-12-30 | NULL | 0 |
| NULL | 2022-12-31 | NULL | 0 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-01 | 10.000000 | 1 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-02 | 10.500000 | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-03 | 11.000000 | 3 |
| 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-04 | 10.666666 | 3 |
| 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-05 | 11.000000 | 3 |
| 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-06 | 10.833333 | 3 |
| 2023-01-05 | 2023-01-07 | 11.633333 | 3 |
| NULL | 2023-01-08 | NULL | 0 |
| NULL | 2023-01-09 | NULL | 0 |

Now some of these are NULL because there's data missing to complete the range, you will need to determine how you want to handle that.